# dynamodb query single row using javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

Not sure what is going on here, I follow the docs, and I get errors, so maybe my table is defined wrong?

```
function parseGET( data, callback )
{
    const params = 
    {
        TableName: data.TableName,
        Key: 
        {
            "workOrder": data.workOrder  // <--number, not a string
        }
    };

    dynamodb.get( params, ( error, data ) =>
    {
        if( error )
            console.log( 'table ERROR:', error );
    ...
    }
}
```

Response: "The provided key element does not match the schema"

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "The provided key element does not match the schema",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
}
```

If I do a scan, I get all my data, but I just want to get a single row.

```
dynamodb.scan( {"TableName": data.TableName}, ( error, data ) =>
...
data:
{
  "probeCount": "123",
  "rangeCal": "hight",
  "ESID": "1",
  "rangeNom": "1000",
  "nodeCount": "123",
  "password": "123",
  "cableLength": "456",
  "userId": "Onicon",
  "usePasswd": "disable",
  "elevation": "789",
  "workOrder": 789456,
  "rangeMax": "1150",
  "serialNumber": "3"
}
  ],
  "Count": 11,
  "ScannedCount": 11
```

Getting a single row works in the console, but I can't figure out how to do the same via JS.

Some table details:

```
Table name  myTestTable
Primary partition key   workOrder (Number)
Primary sort key    -
Point-in-time recovery  DISABLEDEnable
Time to live attribute  DISABLEDManage TTL
Table status    Active
Creation date   March 22, 2018 at 1:45:09 PM UTC-7
UTC: March 22, 2018 at 8:45:09 PM UTC

Local: March 22, 2018 at 1:45:09 PM UTC-7

Region (N. California): March 22, 2018 at 12:45:09 PM UTC-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to those who helped.
The end result was I was a little confused (as usual).
`data.workOrder` was a string of a number, eg. `"654"` in JSON, not `654`.
So the simple solution is to convert it to an actual number:

`data.workOrder = parseInt( data.workOrder, 10 );`

And now my original query works!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the definition of your key to something like...

```
Key: 
  {
    "workOrder": {"N", data.workOrder}  // <--number, not a string
  }
```

you might need to use

```
data.workOrder.toString()
```

when defining the key.

Comment: That Key syntax is giving me a syntax error, Unexpected Token.

Comment: That gives me "null" result with/or without the toString() method.  BTW, what is the "N"?  I see it used in the docs, but not finding a definition for it.

Comment: the "N" says the datatype that follows is a number even though it is represented as a string. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html